# Simple SQL query not executing

Tags: sql

I am familiar with MySQL, and was under the impression that Microsoft SQL wasn't that different in syntax for the simple stuff.

So whenever I wanted to update the **Published** field (a boolean) on every row on a table called **Country** to false, I did this:

```
UPDATE Country SET Published = false;
```

When I execute the query, I get this error:

[image: Error]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the value for `Published` with single quote,

```
UPDATE Country SET Published = 'false';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Add [ and ]

UPDATE Country SET [Published] = false;
```

Comment: `Published` is not areserved word.

Comment: Yes, the column in error msg was about false. And yes published is not a reserved word I checked after posting. Should use 0 for bit type field I guess.